# Trains scheduled, find max platforms per stations

Tags: java, algorithm, hash-map

> Given a "folder" which contains many "files," each file contains a time-table of trains, which stations they halt on and what time, per day.
>
> ```
> File-1 for day-1
> Train1    [station1, <1  - 3> ] [station2, <5  - 6> ] 
> Train2    [station1, <10 - 12>] [station3, <15 - 18>] 
>
> File-2 for day-2
> Train1    [station1,  <11  - 4> ] [station2, <5  - 6> ] 
> Train2    [station1, <8 -   2>] [station3, <15 - 18>]
> ```
>
> Overlapping days are included in the same file.
>
> E.g: If trains halt from 23.00 - 00.30 then this data would be present
>   in one of the files only.
>
> We ignore timezones and use 00 - 23.59 scale instead of am and pm.
>
> To find how many platforms a station would need given such daily
>   schedules.
>
> E.g: If `Train1` and `Train2` both use `Station1` from 10 - 12 then
>   `Station1` needs two platforms.
>
> **Complexity:**
>
> \$O\$ ( file * stations * (intervals * log intervals) )
>
> - file - each file in the folder, aka number of days, whose schedule has been given :
>              constituted by - `for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {`
> - stations - constituted by `dailyStationPlatformCountMap()`
> - intervals - sort inside `maxOverlappingInterval`

Note: I do understand merits of unit testing in separate files. But I deliberately added it to the main method for personal convenience, so I request that you don't consider that in your feedback.

I'm looking for request code review, optimizations and best practices.

```
final class Intervals implements Serializable {
    private final int start;
    private final int end;

    public Intervals (int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public int getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
}

public final class TrainTimeTable {

    private TrainTimeTable() { }

    public static Map<String, Integer> stationMaxPlatformMap(String folderName) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        File folder = new File(folderName);
        final List<Map<String, Integer>> stationPlatformCountList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Integer>>();
        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (file.toString().contains("DS_Store")) continue;
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            final Map<String, Map<String, Intervals>> dailyTrainStationIntervalMap = (Map<String, Map<String, Intervals>>) ois.readObject();
            final Map<String, List<Intervals>> dailyStationIntervalMap = getDailyPerStationIntervalMap(dailyTrainStationIntervalMap);
            final Map<String, Integer> dailyStationPlatformCountMap = dailyStationPlatformCountMap(dailyStationIntervalMap);
            stationPlatformCountList.add(dailyStationPlatformCountMap);
        }
        return yearlyMaxPlatforms(stationPlatformCountList);
    }

    /**
     * Breaks down the the information 'per train' into information 'per station'
     * From here on the 'trains' don't hold any relevance, as we have created the time-table per station.
     * ie - all intervals with respect to a station are mapped to the station.
     * 
     * @param trainStationIntervalMap   :  map of trains -> to stations and train's intervals on those stations
     * @return                          :  map of station -> to all intervals of all trains on that station.
     */
    private static Map<String, List<Intervals>> getDailyPerStationIntervalMap(Map<String, Map<String, Intervals>> trainStationIntervalMap) {
        final Map<String, List<Intervals>> dailyStationInterval = new HashMap<String, List<Intervals>>();
        for (Map<String, Intervals>  map  : trainStationIntervalMap.values()) {
            for (Entry<String, Intervals> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                final String station = entry.getKey();
                final Intervals interval = entry.getValue();

                if (!dailyStationInterval.containsKey(station)) {
                    dailyStationInterval.put(station, new ArrayList<Intervals>());
                }
                dailyStationInterval.get(station).add(interval);
            }
        }
        return dailyStationInterval;
    }


    /**
     * Given a map of station -> all intervals belonging to the station, return the maximum platforms that may be needed.
     * 
     * @param dailyStationIntervalMap   : map of station -> all intervals of that station.
     * @return
     */
    private static Map<String, Integer> dailyStationPlatformCountMap(Map<String, List<Intervals>> dailyStationIntervalMap) {
        final Map<String, Integer> dailyStationMaxPlatformCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Entry<String, List<Intervals>> entry : dailyStationIntervalMap.entrySet()) { 
            String station = entry.getKey();
            List<Intervals> intervalList = entry.getValue();
            dailyStationMaxPlatformCount.put(station,  maxOverlappingInterval(intervalList));
        }
        return dailyStationMaxPlatformCount;
    }

    /**
     * Given a station and its intervals, find the max platforms needed.
     * Station is a 'meeting room'
     * interval is understandably 'interval'
     * platforms simply corresponds to 'overlap'
     * 
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969823/how-to-find-the-maximal-number-of-these-intervals-that-have-a-common-point
     * 
     * @param startTime
     * @param endTime
     * @return
     */
    private static int maxOverlappingInterval (List<Intervals> interval) {
        int[] startTime = new int[interval.size()];
        int[] endTime = new int[interval.size()];

        populateAndSort(startTime, endTime, interval);

        int i = 0;  // ctr for start time array
        int j = 0;  // ctr for end time array
        int count  = 0;
        int max = -1;

        while (i < startTime.length) {
            if (startTime[i]  < endTime[j]) {
                count++;
                i++;
                if (count > max) {
                    max = count;
                }
            } else if (startTime[i] > endTime[j]) {
                count--;
                j++;
            } else {
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    private static void populateAndSort(int[] startTime, int[] endTime, List<Intervals> interval) {
        for (int i = 0; i < interval.size(); i++) {
            startTime[i] = interval.get(i).getStart();
            endTime[i] = interval.get(i).getEnd();
        }
        Arrays.sort(startTime);
        Arrays.sort(endTime);
    }

    /**
     * Once a list of 365 maps of Stations -> max plaform needed per day, we need to find, 
     * wbat was the max platform needed by Station for entire year.
     * Example:
     * If station "foo" needed 6 plaforms on Jan 16, and 4 plaforms on July 8th, then 6 should be added to map.
     * ie 
     * foo -> 6
     * bar -> 8 etc.
     * 
     * @param stationPlatformCountList  : list of daily station to max platform count per day map.
     * @return
     */
    private static Map<String, Integer> yearlyMaxPlatforms(List<Map<String, Integer>> stationPlatformCountList) {
        final Map<String, Integer> yearlyStationPlatformCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < stationPlatformCountList.size(); i++) {
            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : stationPlatformCountList.get(i).entrySet()) {
                String station = entry.getKey();
                int platformCount = entry.getValue();
                if (!yearlyStationPlatformCountMap.containsKey(station) || yearlyStationPlatformCountMap.get(station) < platformCount) {
                    yearlyStationPlatformCountMap.put(station, platformCount);
                }
            } 
        }
        return yearlyStationPlatformCountMap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // create a directory:
        new File("/Users/ameya.patil/Desktop/schedules").mkdir(); 

        Map<String, Map<String, Intervals>> map1 = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Intervals>>();

        Map<String, Intervals> stationInterval11 = new HashMap<String, Intervals>();
        stationInterval11.put("Churchgate", new Intervals(1, 2));
        stationInterval11.put("Dadar", new Intervals(4, 6));
        stationInterval11.put("Bandra", new Intervals(8, 10));
        map1.put("T1", stationInterval11);

        Map<String, Intervals> stationInterval12 = new HashMap<String, Intervals>();
        stationInterval12.put("Churchgate", new Intervals(1, 3));
        stationInterval12.put("Dadar", new Intervals(6, 9));
        stationInterval12.put("Bandra", new Intervals(12, 15));
        map1.put("T2", stationInterval12);

        Map<String, Intervals> stationInterval13 = new HashMap<String, Intervals>();
        stationInterval13.put("Churchgate", new Intervals(1, 4));
        stationInterval13.put("Dadar",      new Intervals(5, 9));
        stationInterval13.put("Bandra",     new Intervals(13, 17));
        map1.put("T3", stationInterval13);

        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/Users/ameya.patil/Desktop/schedules/dayOne"))) {
            oos.writeObject(map1);
        }

        Map<String, Map<String, Intervals>> map2 = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Intervals>>();

        Map<String, Intervals> stationInterval21 = new HashMap<String, Intervals>();
        stationInterval21.put("Churchgate", new Intervals(1, 2));
        stationInterval21.put("Dadar", new Intervals(4, 6));
        stationInterval21.put("Bandra", new Intervals(8, 10));
        map2.put("T1", stationInterval21);

        Map<String, Intervals> stationInterval22 = new HashMap<String, Intervals>();
        stationInterval22.put("Churchgate", new Intervals(1, 3));
        stationInterval22.put("Dadar", new Intervals(6, 9)); 
        stationInterval22.put("Bandra", new Intervals(9, 15));
        map2.put("T2", stationInterval22);

        Map<String, Intervals> stationInterval23 = new HashMap<String, Intervals>();
        stationInterval23.put("Churchgate", new Intervals(12, 14));
        stationInterval23.put("Dadar",      new Intervals(5, 9));
        stationInterval23.put("Bandra",     new Intervals(13, 17));
        map2.put("T3", stationInterval23);

        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/Users/ameya.patil/Desktop/schedules/dayTwo"))) {
            oos.writeObject(map2);
        }

        /**
         * Expected stuff:
         * Dadar  : 2
         * Churchgate  : 3
         * Bandra  : 2
         */
        final Map<String, Integer> expected = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        expected.put("Dadar", 2);
        expected.put("Churchgate", 3);
        expected.put("Bandra", 2);


        assertEquals(expected, stationMaxPlatformMap("/Users/ameya.patil/Desktop/schedules"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick review, but still good coding like usual.

### Naming :

```
int i = 0;  // ctr for start time array
int j = 0;  // ctr for end time array
```

Isn't it better to call them `pointerStartTime` and `pointerEndTime`?
It helps you when you are programming. Take in mind that you get this code and must find a little bug.
  You are getting a headache just by always thinking what `i` and `j` are

### Check for your own faults :

```
private static void populateAndSort(int[] startTime, int[] endTime, List<Intervals> interval) {
    for (int i = 0; i < interval.size(); i++) {
        startTime[i] = interval.get(i).getStart();
        endTime[i] = interval.get(i).getEnd();
    }
    Arrays.sort(startTime);
    Arrays.sort(endTime);
}
```

Its a strange set up and you can make a mistake when you call this method, by not setting the length of the array big enough.
At least this you should be doing :

```
private static void populateAndSort(int[] startTime, int[] endTime, List<Intervals> interval) {
    if ((startTime.length != endTime.length) || (startTime.length != interval.size())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("All sizes must be the same");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < interval.size(); i++) {
        startTime[i] = interval.get(i).getStart();
        endTime[i] = interval.get(i).getEnd();
    }
    Arrays.sort(startTime);
    Arrays.sort(endTime);
}
```

To avoid "abuse" of the method you should do the creation of the `int[]` in your method self :

```
private static Map<String,int[]> getTimesFromIntervals (List<Intervals> intervals>) {
```

In the javaDoc you tell exactly that the key for `startTime[]` is `starttime` and so on.
This is then clear for every programmer that will use that method.
You see that I cut the sorting to from that method.
I prefer a new method for sorting the 2 arrays :

```
private static void sortIntegerMap (Map<String,int[]> timesMap) {
    for (int[] time : timesMap.values()) {
        Arrays.sort(time);
    }
}
```

Now you have a more generic method that can sort, even more entries in the map is no problem.

Hope you have something from this review.